# How to get PC spec over local network?

Tags: windows, ip

In my network , computers use ip adresses with range of 10.12.0.1-120.
Is there any way to get spec (CPU, VGA, RAM, HDD) each of PC's over network ??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Belarc is one good tool. There are others.

https://www.belarc.com/products_belarc_advisor

It can inventory a remote computer

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/369734-running-belarc-advisor-against-remote-computer

Google for PC Inventory

Comment: Does this work over the network? @John

Comment: Yes, so far as I know.  https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/369734-running-belarc-advisor-against-remote-computer .  I added this to my answer

Answer (score 2):

Windows can do this all by itself.

Simple way

```
systeminfo /s 127.0.0.1
```

OR

```
msinfo32
```

then look on the View menu to connect to a remote computer

Or for thousands of settings

`wmic` is the console interface to Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI), which is Windows' implementation of Web Based Enterprise Management (WBEM).

```
wmic /node:127.0.0.1 computersystem get /format:list
```

Or for many computers at a time

First get a text file of turned on computers

```
for /f "skip=3 delims=\" %%A in ('net view ^| findstr /v /C:"The command completed successfully"') do Echo %%A >> ComputerList.txt
```

then

```
wmic /node:@"c:\somefolder\ComputerList.txt" computersystem get /format:list
```

See `wmic /?`, `wmic /node /?`, `wmic computersystem get /?`. Also see `wmic /failfast /?` Turning this on it doesn't wait for timeouts if a computer is turned off.

Examples

```
wmic cpu get /format:csv
```

To get only some properties

```
wmic cpu get description,manufacturer /format:list
```

To start a program remotely (programs are invisible on remote computers but not the local computer)

```
wmic /node:127.0.0.1 process call create "C:\\windows\\notepad.exe"
```

Note filepaths backslashes must be doubled

Next one outputs a list of processes in an html table.

```
wmic process get /format:htable

wmic process get /format:htable > "%userprofile%\Desktop\ProcessList.html"
```